# Comparar menor prazo entre colunas asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, entity-framework

Fazendo sistema de pedido, eu tenho varios armazens, vamo supor que eu tenha que comparar 2 armazens que tenha menor prazo de entrega usando entityframework,como eu faria isso? eu estou tentando fazer mais ele só retorna o ultimo valor consultado, mas não o menor. no código abaixo, eu tenho um foreach que percorre 2 armazens e no final ele me retornaria apenas o com menor prazo de entrega

```
                foreach (var item2 in lstDeposito)
            {

                Armazem arm = db.Armazem.Find(item2.Deposito.ArmazemId);

                var de = db.Armazem.Where(x => x.Id == arm.Id).Min(x => x.Prazo);

                int menorprazo = Convert.ToInt32(de);
            }
```

Armazen

```
public class Armazem
{
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        public int Prazo { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Deposito> Deposito { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como o lstDeposito tem os armazéns, você pode ordenar e pegar o ultimo registro:

```
var armazen = lstDeposito.OrderByDescending(x => x.Prazo).Take(1);

int menorprazo = armazen.prazo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiz alguns testes aqui, e seu código retorna o menor valor corretamente, fiz testes com outras tabelas, mas a ideia é a mesma:

```
var valorMenorSalario = context.Funcionarios
                  .Where(x => x.Nome.Equals("Richard"))
                  .Min(x => x.Salario).Value;
```

No meu caso, tenho mais funcionários com o nome `Richard` mas estou pegando o menor dos salários entre eles.

Uma dica que posso te dar é você saber o que está sendo consultado pelo Entity Framework, adicione esse código (Se você ainda não tiver) no `CONSTRUTOR`do seu `CONTEXT`:

```
    class PiccoloContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Funcionario> Funcionarios { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Pagamento> Pagamentos { get; set; }

        public PiccoloContext() : base("Piccolo")
        { 
           Database.Log = sql => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sql);
        }
    }
```

Essa linha: `Database.Log = sql => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sql);`
Permite que você possa ver o que o Entity Framework está fazendo para consultar no Banco, é só você abrir a aba `OutPut`ou `Saída` do seu Visual Studio que assim que passar pela consulta ele irá mostrar o código feito, dessa forma:

[image: SQL Feito pelo Entity Framework]
Então você pega esse código e consulta no Banco de Dados que você está utilizando, pode copiar e colar lá que irá funcionar.
No meu caso a tabela era essa:

[image: Tabela Funcionarios]

E o resultado foi esse com a consulta:
[image: Resultado da Consulta Feita pelo Entity]